# When retrieving time stamp in rails, it is being converted or rounded down. How do I prevent this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a completed_at column on my database with the values `2021-03-05 00:17:31.059123`, and `2021-03-05 00:08:00.257058` but when I retrieve this it's showing/displaying `Thu, 04 Mar 2021 16:17:31 PST -08:00`, and `Thu, 04 Mar 2021 16:08:00 PST -08:00` respectively.

How is it on my database it's displaying `March 5, 2021` but when I retrieve the data it's `March 4, 2021`. Is there a way to prevent this?

Ruby version: 2.3.6

Rails version: 4.2.6

Postgres version: 9.6

Comment: Because of the time zones, you can configure that for your Rails app.

Comment: @Eyeslandic Do you know where can I find this in rails documentation? Is it in date time?

Comment: Here is one example https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because Rails uses your app timezone (see `Time.zone`) but when the date is stored in the database, is stored in UTC. As such, if you inspect the timestamp on your database, for instance, using a GUI to inspect a table and its rows, you will see that date in UTC.

Try to set your app time zone to something else. Open the rails console, and play with it:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007ff13688d180 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Etc/UTC>>

irb(main):002:0> User.last.created_at
  User Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> Tue, 26 Jan 2021 13:47:58.769517000 UTC +00:00

irb(main):003:0> Time.zone = "Alaska"
=> "Alaska"

irb(main):004:0> User.last.created_at
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> Tue, 26 Jan 2021 04:47:58.769517000 AKST -09:00

irb(main):006:0> User.last.created_at.utc
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 2021-01-26 13:47:58.769517 UTC
```

Some reading recommendations:

[The Exhaustive Guide to Rails Time Zones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/) and [WORKING WITH TIME ZONES IN RUBY ON RAILS](https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/).

You can also see the documentation for [TimeWithZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html), [Time](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) and [TimeZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).